# Best way to implement process output in ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line, gradle

In `gradle build`, I can see current process like following:

```
# first is
> Loading
# and then change to 
> Configuring > 0/1 projects > root project
```

**my question is:** how to output current process in one line not two lines, for instance:

```
# first is:
> 0/46 download tasks are finished
# and then change this line to
> 1/46 downaload tasks are finished
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use carriage return key `\r` to reprint on the same line, overriding the previous:

```
10.times { |i| print "\r#{i}/10 times"; sleep 1 }
# => 5/10 times
```

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/paul/progress_bar gem for such tasks.

The output looks like this:

```
[#######################################                           ] [ 59.00%] [00:06]
```

And you can easily configure it for your needs.